# SvelteKit: Unable to access Paths without '.html' extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, svelte, sveltekit

I'm experiencing issues with SvelteKit routes. I have a web application that utilizes Svelte, and when I upload it to the server, I can only access the routes by appending '.html' to the end of the path. Otherwise, the server denies access.

For instance:

- https://myurl/home -> returns an access denied error.
- https://myurl/home.html -> displays the page.

Does anyone know how to assist me in avoiding the need to add '.html' to each path? I have attempted to search if others have faced the same issue, but have not found any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set [`trailingSlash`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#trailingslash) in the root layout:

```
export const trailingSlash = 'always';
```

That way it generates directories with `index.html` files.